# How to get random time in certain time format

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, random

I want to get date from 2013/01/01 to Today. Plus time from 14:00 to 23:00 but the time interval is 15min.

For example:

```
2013/01/01 14:15
2013/01/21 14:30
2013/01/21 17:45
2013/03/17 14:00
.
.
.
```

For the date, I can use the code below but I'm not sure of the time part

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
Random gen = new Random();
int range = (DateTime.Today - start).Days;           
start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
```

Comment: Looks like a random integer in the range 0 to 36, multiplied by 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
int startHour = 14;
int endHour = 23;
int allQuarters = Enumerable.Range(0, (endHour - startHour) * 4).Count();
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(gen.Next(allQuarters) * 15);
start = start + TimeSpan.FromHours(startHour) + time;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/XIfst2)